# UITableViewCell ReuseIdentifier Behavior [obj-c]

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am curious as to the behavior of the reuse identifier system.
I am working with a uitableviewcell that has two different uilabels on them.
Label one is always there and is updating correctly, 
Label two starts with .alpha=0 and appears on a certain condition within the specific cell.

Label one is acting as suspected, 
Label two acts strangely, when I first load the scene(viewdidload) it appears as it should.
When I scroll down and find a uitableviewcell has the labeltwo with .alpha=1 because it satisfied the conditional.

Up to this point everything is working, but now if I scroll back up, all label two's have an .alpha=1.

After doing some research, I have come to the conclusion that this has to do with me redefining what the reuse identifier cell template actually looks like programatically. 
My question is , is there a way to reset the "buffer" to the uitableview cell i have created in storyboard that DOESNT have the changes I have made programatically.
Also since these are my own deductions, I may be incorrect in my assumptions, 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Provide us your cellForRow method, please.

Answer (score 1):

Your cells begins .alpha = 1, because of reuseIdentifier, that already see .alpha = 1, and set another sell to this parameter. As a first decision, you can control .alpha parameter for the each cell individually.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"FeedbackCell";

    VZDetailFeedbackTableViewCell *cell = (VZDetailFeedbackTableViewCell *)[self.p_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[VZDetailFeedbackTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    // There can be more cells with Identifier

    CGFloat alpha = 1.0f;
    //if (something) 
   {
      alpha = 0.0f;
   }
   [cell setSellAlpha:alpha];
}

// In your custom cell class you make method setAlpha and there control visibility
```